# Use KentorAuthServices with IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, kentor-authservices, asp.net-core-identity

I want to use IdentiyServer4 and add KentorAuthServices middleware for SAML authentication.

From the [IdentityServer4 documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html#adding-support-for-external-authentication.) it suggests to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies` package and use the middleware with SignIn type as `IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme`.

I configured the same but couldn't get the access_token in variable `info`.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
                return View("~/Home/Index");
            }

            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        }
```

Here I get zero entries in `info.AuthenticationTokens` property. Did I need some customizations in Kentor.AuthServices (aspnetcorebranch) to support access tokens or need something to configure in identityserver4

Comment: It stated in the aspnetcore branch README that it's still under development and does not build yet. Did you simply grabbed the middleware part and use it in Idsrv4?

Comment: any updates, or an other way to use SSO with Idsrv4? we're currently deciding whether to use Idsrv3 (because of SSO support) or a cloud service (Auth0)